# Adding text to <title></title> if gathered mysql data is new?

Tags: php, html

What is that called and how do you do it? My page refreshes every 10 seconds using jquery querying a database.

I get new tables casually and I want to be able to update the  field to display how many new tables were gathered.  I want this because instead of viewing the page to see if any updates happened I can just look at the title of the page inside a tab instead of switching over every 10 seconds you know?

How can this be done? Thanks.

Also the data I am gathering is text in a small table  and data is just failed admincp user credentials.

Comment: In JavaScript, `document.title` gets you the current page title.  Setting that to something changes the page title.

Comment: If I get the data via PHP by adding my results up and sending to the <title>. Can I use the javascript focus function to change the value if I view the page? Because if I use php and view the page there's no way for me to reset the title unless I create a button or something. I'm not very experienced with php yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the title of a HTML document using JavaScript:

```
var title = "This is my new title, can be anything";    
document.title = title;
```

I don't know how you are storing the number of new fields, but you could use a function like this:

```
function updateTitleBar (newTables)
{
   document.title = newTables;
}
```

... Or you can just use `document.title = newTables` where you define the `newTables` somewhere else (and change that value every time you refresh the page in jQuery).

Comment: ah, I just realized someone else said something similar already.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
<body onload="runTicker()">

    function runTicker(){
        setTimeout("document.title = new Date();runTicker()", 5000);
    }
```

But instead of doing document.title = new Date(), replace that with a call to a function that would make an AJAX call to your PHP script. Perhaps using jquery if you're accustomed to that already?